# Syntax error using LEN() with varchar

Tags: sql

can anyone advise the correct syntax for below.

```
@test len(right(@test, charindex('/',@test) 1)1)  + ' ' + left(@test, charindex('/',@test) 1)  + ' ' +invoice_booking.dptr_date +  ' ' + invoice_booking_detail.destination_name [AS] Description
```

I added the `len()` into it as I want to limit the first result to 1 character

I have also declared `@test` as

```
DECLARE @test nvarchar(100)
SET @test = invoice_booking_detail.principal_passenger
```

Cheers

Dave

Comment: Could you maybe add some kind of problem statement here. And a *complete* example? If no idea *what* you're trying to achieve, nor how close the code you've presented is to achieving that goal, let alone how you'd expect anyone else to fix it?

Comment: MySQL - SQL Server - Oracle ?

Comment: MySQL sorry took a while to see this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong Syntax near `LEN(),LEFT(),RIGHT()`

```
@test LEN(RIGHT(@test, CHARINDEX('/',@test)))  + ' ' + LEFT(@test, CHARINDEX('/',@test))  + ' ' +invoice_booking.dptr_date +  ' ' + invoice_booking_detail.destination_name [AS] Description
```

Comment: Hi, tested the above when I got home. Still not working. Syntax error near right.

Answer (score 0):

here is the complete statement:

```
    DECLARE @test nvarchar(100)
    SET @test = invoice_booking_detail.principal_passenger
    SELECT
    CASE WHEN 
    (Invoice_booking_detail.destination_country_name  = ‘United Kingdom’)     then ‘T1’
ELSE ‘6130’
END AS [Nominal Code],
‘F200’ AS [Cost Centre],
Case when
(Invoice_booking.booking_type_description = ‘Flight’ )then ‘T2’
When
(Invoice_booking.booking_type_description = ‘Hotel’) then ‘T3’
When
(Invoice_booking.booking_type_description = ‘Rail’ )then ‘T9’
Else ‘T999’
END AS [Travel Project Code],
‘0’ AS  [Always ‘0000],
‘ ‘,
‘ ‘,
‘ ‘,
‘ ‘,
‘ ‘,
Case when 
(invoice_booking_detail.invoice_nett_amount < 0) then 0
When
(invoice_booking_detail.invoice_nett_amount >= 0) then     invoice_booking_detail.invoice_nett_amount
END AS [Amount DR],
Case when 
(invoice_booking_detail.invoice_nett_amount >= 0) then 0
When
(invoice_booking_detail.invoice_nett_amount < 0) then     invoice_booking_detail.invoice_nett_amount
END AS [Amount CR],

‘ ‘,
‘ ‘,

@test len(right(@test, charindex(‘/’,@test) 1)1)  + ' ' + left(@test,     charindex(‘/’,@test) 1)  + ' ' +invoice_booking.dptr_date +  '  ' +     invoice_booking_detail.destination_name [AS] Description

FROM TEST.invoice_booking invoice_booking,
TEST.invoice_booking_detail invoice_booking_detail

WHERE invoice_booking.trans_number = invoice_booking_detail.trans_number AND
invoice_booking.company = invoice_booking_detail.company AND
invoice_booking.branch_code = invoice_booking_detail.branch_code AND 
invoice_booking.trip = invoice_booking_detail.trip AND 
invoice_booking.booking = invoice_booking_detail.booking AND 
invoice_booking_detail.bill_to_customer_id like 'TEST ACCOUNT%'
ORDER BY invoice_booking_detail.principal_passenger
```